# Obtain coordinates in R

Tags: r, plot, candlestick-chart

I would like to obtain coordinates on a plot.

First of all, I'm plotting a `candleChart` in R and I want to obtain the coordinates of the last candlestick  and add a `.png` image on it.

The code of is the following:

```
candleChart(eje.xts,subset = "last 3 months",name=mensaje,TA=c(addMACD(),addRSI(),addBBands()),theme = "white",up.col = "green",dn.col="red")
```

Where `eje.xts` is the data of the form: Date,Open, High,Low,Close

Is there a way to obtain that?

[I want to obtain the some coordinate of the rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNoI2.png)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: show code or your `candleChart`

Comment: @Batanichek Done, sorry for that :)

Comment: With the plot open, call `locator(1)`, click on the position and you will get the coordinates.

Comment: Hi @nicola. It is a good idea, but I would like to automatize the proces...